# How do you get information about address URL in POST method using C#?

Tags: c#, url, post, networking

Just wondering if there is a way to check for the address URL in POST request before it will be sent to server using C#?

When POST request is sent, you can see all the details but can you actually see it before it has been sent from your web browser? (especially if it is embedded into a website using certain engines; which means you cannot inspect buttons using right-click)

I'm referring to these information:

[image: Information Method POST Request]

Such things are usually executed via some sort of user-interaction, like a button/form or similar.

Comment: `Just wondering if there is a way to check for the address URL in POST request before it will be sent to server using C#?` This would require some javascript, are you using a framework of just vanilla JS?

Comment: I am not using any JavaScript at the moment. Only C# (Visual Studio) to execute POST requests using Windows Forms, and currently trying to get the 'Request URL' into a variable. If JavaScript is required, it would be cool if could you point me in the right direction

Comment: To make sure I understand you, You want a WINDOWS FORMS app to POST to some C# service, and before you post you want the C# service to examine the post information?

Comment: If that's possible, yes. I can already successfully send POST but need the right information. But if it is not possible then I was thinking of another alternative, like executing some sort of HttpWebRequest listener service, in which it checks for all POST requests that are being sent via Web Browser and if certain word is caught in during the request, it will get the header information that way.

Comment: What type of service do you have i.e WebAPI,WCF,ASMX,WebMethods?

Comment: It's based on this code here (Example section); https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class